# Django App on Elastic Beanstalk not Inserting to Specific Model in Deployed Version (works locally)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django web application that is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, with a PostgreSQL database on AWS RDS. I have a strange issue where data updates in the UI are inserted to the model locally, but not in the deployed version. Additionally, it's only for one specific model. The other models take UI inputs fine in the deployment.

Again, this works perfectly locally, but not when deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. The weird part is that the other models in the application work fine in both local and deployed versions. Since it works locally, and only one model is impacted I don't necessarily know what code would be beneficial to post, and don't want to flood the post with unecessary code but I will be happy to provide relevant code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have reviewed the RDS logs, the Elastic Beanstalk logs, and access the EB instance using `eb ssh` to review additional logs there but find no indication of an error occurring.

Comment: This issue occurred because my deployment environment had a more updated version of django than my development branch. My development django handled default values differently than the deployment, which made the database update requests invalid.

Comment: consider using docker, so you get the same version on EBS as well.